# Understanding floating point arithmetic with an example

Tags: arithmetic, computer-science

Im trying to understand FPA. Taking an example, suppose

$$ f(x) = \frac{ 1 }{1-x} - \frac{1}{1+x} $$

$x \neq \pm  1$. So, to compute this expression, we are using 2 divisions and one substraction, thus giving 3 operation. Are there values for which it is dificult to compute such expression in floating point arithmetic? I would guess for values near the restrictions. Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct. For $x$ sufficiently close to $\pm 1$ the difference will eventually evaluate to one of the two terms due to the different scales. See also [Floating point inaccuracy examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A difficulty (but perhaps not the only) arises near $x = 0$.  For example, analytically, $f = g$ where

$$
g(x) = \frac{2x}{1 - x^2}
$$

but as $x \to 0$, $1 \pm x \approx 1$ and $1 - x^2 \approx 1$, both because the mantissa precision is limited, so $f(x) \approx 0$ but $g(x) \approx 2 x$.  Clearly, analytically $f(x)\neq0$ for $x \neq 0$, so rearranging the formula symbolically before evaluation as $g(x)$ gives a more accurate result.

**Note:** Here I am using $\approx$ to denote floating point equality, not an approximate equality.

Answer (score 0):

[Machine $\epsilon$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)  is the smallest number such that $$1+\epsilon >1$$ which implies that, if $x <\epsilon$, then, at machine level, $1\pm x=1$ and, then, the problems for the kind of expression you posted.

This does not have anything to do with the smallest number of a real kind you could effectively compute.

Answer (score 0):

Major sources of errors tend to be where you do an addition or subtraction that causes cancellation.

So, the values of $x$ to worry about are the solutions to:

- $1-x = 0$
- $1+x = 0$
- $\frac{ 1 }{1-x} - \frac{1}{1+x} = 0$

So the values to potentially worry about are when $x$ is near $1$, $-1$, $0$, $+\infty$, or $-\infty$.

Near $\pm \infty$, the two terms in the third equation have opposite sign, so although the difference is near zero, there isn't any cancellation. So, the only remaining worries are $1, -1, 0$. (and, they really are problems)